# Правильная верстка адаптивного блока

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Необходимо сверстать блок и в тоже время растянуть левую картинку на всю ширину от центра(50%) и также текст в рамках сетки. Как это правильно сделать? Я подумывал сделать на флексах фоны в блоке по отдельность и блок с текстом и кнопкой сверху но не уверен что это правильный способ. На нашел к сожеленью похожего ответа в инете. Буду очень блогодарен. Прикладываю скрин с макета. [image: Скрин с исходника]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в таком духе:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.foo {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: orange;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 -20px;
}

.container-item {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/800" alt="#">
    </div>

    <div class="container-item">
      <h2>Lorem, ipsum.</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis aut facilis aspernatur, cum architecto cupiditate. Mollitia ab magni fuga aperiam.</p>

      <button>Click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за отзывчивость! Может я неправильно выразился но проблема именно в фонах, то есть текст придерживается сетки а картинка и желтый фон покрывают экран на 100%(Резиновые), как это реализовать?

Comment: я бы ставил максимальную ширину 100% и min-width ибо на мобилках все ломается

Comment: Извините что тяну время, я об отображений на пк, не об адаптивность(это конечно тоже важно), вот макет http://prntscr.com/ueznm1 нужно сделать ровно также но не получаеться тк фон разделен на две картинки которые растянуты от центра экрана, глупый вопрос но большего опыта нету покачто..

Comment: @VictorL, выложите пример того, что вы сделали, а-то ничего не понятно

Comment: http://prntscr.com/uf004o - вот наглядно, текст выходит за рамки сетки(неправильно) и картинка также не занимает 50% экрана(тоже не по макету)..

Comment: просто задайте max-width для текста

Comment: @VictorL поставьте min-width: 50vw для img или для элемента-родителя этой картинки, если она вложена